# How to drive robot without driving actuator?

Tags: line-following

I am participating in a robotics competition. I am supposed to design and build two robots. Out of these, one **cannot have a driving actuator** (it can have a steering actuator though, fed by a line following circuit). The other is supposed to drive the non-driving robot through an obstacle course, *without touching it*. This is kind of driving me crazy since at one point the separation between the two robots is 60 cm (23 inches).

Ways I've considered:

1. Wind Energy (wont work, need huge sails)
2. Magnetic Repulsion of some sort

Now repulsion I've spent a lot of time studying.

My solution was to use strong permanent magnets on the non-driving robot (Neodymium,N52) and electromagnets on the driving robot.

But, after doing a huge load of calculations came to the conclusion that not enough force can be transmitted over the distance as magnetic fields fall off too quick.

Rulebook: http://ultimatist.com/video/Rulebook2016_Final_website_1_Sep_15.zip

I am really looking for even a pointer here. Is there a trick somewhere that I am missing?

Comment: It is an exact duplicate of that question, actually.

Comment: Is it driving you crazy with or without an actuator?

Comment: I have to say, those rules are pretty insane, and it seems to me only veteran roboticists would be able to tackle some of the challenges presented. Sounds like a DARPA project.